# Specify a systemd unit for cronjob

Tags: cron, systemd-journald, systemd-unit, anacron

When I run a cronjob, it's nice being able to follow its logs. If I want to see all logs from cron with `journalctl`, I can select the `cron` unit (`journalctl -u cron`). But when I have multiple cronjobs, it's not very helpful filtering only for the cron unit.

**Is there some way to filter for a specific cronjob in `journalctl`, or even specify a certain unit that it should belong to?**

Comment: Is using a systemd timer instead of cron an option? Then you can treat the timer's service like any other service

Comment: That is an option, but I've never found them as convenient. Mostly because it's another structure to learn, but also because a cronjob is quite literally one line which is executed exactly as it reads (while systemd timers are one .service-file and one .timer file, or something like that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since these are simply messages from cron, the metadata is all about cron. Example for a couple of messages about a cronjob, using `--output=json`:

```
{
  "__CURSOR": "s=74429436aba942b6bbfc70cf45bfecc6;i=188d;b=108f80cdd87342bcb9dcafca15c45b57;m=6c13fcb19;t=5697ae32bb8a9;x=d292b55b7b7a140d",
  "__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP": "1523351401773225",
  "__MONOTONIC_TIMESTAMP": "29011987225",
  "_BOOT_ID": "108f80cdd87342bcb9dcafca15c45b57",
  "PRIORITY": "6",
  "_UID": "0",
  "_GID": "0",
  "_CAP_EFFECTIVE": "3fffffffff",
  "_MACHINE_ID": "5a75b95396344578a23193fb7b823946",
  "_HOSTNAME": "muru-1604",
  "_SYSTEMD_SLICE": "system.slice",
  "_TRANSPORT": "syslog",
  "SYSLOG_FACILITY": "10",
  "SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER": "CRON",
  "MESSAGE": "pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)",
  "_COMM": "cron",
  "_EXE": "/usr/sbin/cron",
  "_CMDLINE": "/usr/sbin/CRON -f",
  "_AUDIT_LOGINUID": "0",
  "_SYSTEMD_CGROUP": "/system.slice/cron.service",
  "_SYSTEMD_UNIT": "cron.service",
  "SYSLOG_PID": "22158",
  "_PID": "22158",
  "_AUDIT_SESSION": "110",
  "_SOURCE_REALTIME_TIMESTAMP": "1523351401772733"
}
{
  "__CURSOR": "s=74429436aba942b6bbfc70cf45bfecc6;i=188e;b=108f80cdd87342bcb9dcafca15c45b57;m=6c13fcba9;t=5697ae32bb939;x=33e51a528b0cef96",
  "__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP": "1523351401773369",
  "__MONOTONIC_TIMESTAMP": "29011987369",
  "_BOOT_ID": "108f80cdd87342bcb9dcafca15c45b57",
  "PRIORITY": "6",
  "_UID": "0",
  "_GID": "0",
  "_CAP_EFFECTIVE": "3fffffffff",
  "_MACHINE_ID": "5a75b95396344578a23193fb7b823946",
  "_HOSTNAME": "muru-1604",
  "_SYSTEMD_SLICE": "system.slice",
  "_TRANSPORT": "syslog",
  "SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER": "CRON",
  "_COMM": "cron",
  "_EXE": "/usr/sbin/cron",
  "_CMDLINE": "/usr/sbin/CRON -f",
  "_AUDIT_LOGINUID": "0",
  "_SYSTEMD_CGROUP": "/system.slice/cron.service",
  "_SYSTEMD_UNIT": "cron.service",
  "SYSLOG_FACILITY": "9",
  "MESSAGE": "(root) CMD ([ -x /usr/sbin/dma ] && /usr/sbin/dma -q1)",
  "_AUDIT_SESSION": "110",
  "SYSLOG_PID": "22159",
  "_PID": "22159",
  "_SOURCE_REALTIME_TIMESTAMP": "1523351401773201"
}
```

These two are related (see for example, the PIDs or the timestamps), but that relation is not easily expressed as a filter.

As such, there's not much that `journalctl` do for you.

---

If you use a systemd timer, then the corresponding unit can of course be used as filter for `journalctl` (along with all the other benefits of systemd timers: check for next runtime, run a job immediately, properly stopping a long-running cronjob, etc.).

Comment: Too bad to hear, but it answers my question.